# Getting the word "extend" when passing the key on a button click event within a for-in loop

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop

I have a json that looks like this:

```
contacts = [{"id":"0001","title":"Mr","name_first":"Bob","name_last":"Edwards","address1":"2 ford road","address2":null,"address3":null,"town":"Bedford","county":"Bedfordshire","postcode":"Mk16hd","telephone1":"01827485999","telephone2":null,"email":"bob@email.com"},
{"id":"8003","title":"Mr","name_first":"Joe","name_last":"Bloggs","address1":"186 Bath Road","address2":null,"address3":null,"town":null,"county":null,"postcode":null,"telephone1":"01827485648","telephone2":null,"email":"joe@email.com"},
{"id":"R005","title":"Mr","name_first":"Foo","name_last":"Bar","address1":null,"address2":null,"address3":null,"town":null,"county":null,"postcode":null,"telephone1":"01827485647","telephone2":null,"email":"foo@email.com"}];
```

I then loop through this like this, creating a button for each one:

```
for (var key in contacts) { 
    if (contacts.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var contact = contacts[key];

        var button = document.createElement('button');
        button.innerHTML = '<span class="left-body">Edit</span>';
        button.onclick = function() { editContact(key); return false; };
    }
}
```

When clicking each button I get the word "extend" as the value of index in the `editContact()`function:

```
function editContact (index) {
    console.log(index);
    return false;
}
```

Q: What is this and how can I set this up so I get the key for each json item into the `editContact()` function?

Comment: FYI, `contacts` is an array, not JSON. Even if you initially get the data as JSON and then parse it, your problem does not have anything to do with JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of closure

```
for (var key in contacts) { 
    if (contacts.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var contact = contacts[key];

        var button = document.createElement('button');
        button.innerHTML = '<span class="left-body">Edit</span>';
        button.onclick = (function(key){
            return function() { editContact(key); return false; };
        })(key);
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/T9UKr/)

Answer (score 0):

`contacts` is an array. If you want to loop through the properties of one contact you have to specify it (e.g. with `contact[0]`). If you want to loop through the properties of each contact you have to loop through them:

```
for (var i=0;i<contacts.length;i++) {
    for(var key in contacts[i])
```

Second problem:

```
button.onclick = function() { editContact(key); return false; };
```

Every time you click the button `editContact` is called with the **last** value that was assigned to key. Assuming you want to preserve the value of `key` you can do the following:

```
(function() {
    var currentKey = key;
    button.onclick = function() { editContact(currentKey); return false; };
(());
```

**Edit:**
Since you only want to loop through the contacts you can do the following, if you don't have to support IE < 9 ( or can use a shim):

```
contacts.forEach(function(element, index) {
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.innerHTML = '<span class="left-body">Edit</span>';
    button.onclick = function() { editContact(index); return false; };      
});
```

Comment: No, I only want to create 1 button per contact, so in this example only 3 buttons. I think you have hit the nail on the head though, each click event on the buttons is getting assigned the last key in the loop. This is my main problem.

Comment: I see. But then it's better (and safer for that matter) using a traditional for loop: `for (var index=0;index<contacts.length;index++) {`, where `index` is what `key` is in your example.

Comment: Ok cool, if this really is the safer option I'll go for a traditional loop.

How do I overcome the problem with assigning the current "index" as the parameter editContact(index) on the onclick event?

Comment: If you don't need to support IE < 9 you can even use [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) which makes your code shorter and you would not have the "last assigned" problem in the first place.

Comment: mmmmh yes I do need IE<9 support unfortunately. I was using mootools before:

`Object.each(contacts, function(element, key) {`

and it was working fine. But we're moving away from mootools soon so am using classic javascript from now on.

Comment: You still can use [es5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/blob/master/es5-shim.js) then. It adds the `forEach` method. Would you mind accepting one of the answers?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you click the button, editContact is called with the last value that was assigned to key.
So it needs to preserve the index of json row and use that index for further stuff.

I did it in following way so you can get all the keys from your json.

```
  function addButtons() {

    for ( var key in contacts) {
        if (contacts.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var contact = contacts[key];
            var button = document.createElement('button');
            document.body.appendChild(button);
            button.setAttribute('id', key);
            button.innerHTML = '<span class="left-body">Edit</span>';
            button.onclick = function() {
                editContact(this.id);
                return false;
            };
        }
    }
}


function editContact(index) {
    for ( var key in contacts[index]) {
        console.log("Key :" + key+" Value:"+contacts[index][key]);
    }
    return false;
}
```

My html looks like

```
  <body onload="addButtons();"> </body>
```

Comment: This does work but there are a couple of problems. To my understanding (I was advised) the id of an element cannot be a sole number.

Also, (this only relates to my example) I have "delete" buttons for each contact. If I give the "delete" buttons the same id this invalidate the HTML.

Comment: Now you can get both key and value for your json.Using this code   console.log("Key :" + key+" Value:"+contacts[index][key]);